# How to pass variable value to shell script from go?

Tags: go, golang-migrate, cobra

**shell.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
npx create-react-app <project-name> --template typescript
```

`run.go`

```
func runScript(genErr *error) {
    if *genErr != nil {
        return
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", shell)
    *genErr = cmd.Run()
}
```

`details.go`

```
type npmLibCommand struct {
    ProjectName string
}

var npmLib npmLibCommand

func getNpmLibraryInput(genErr *error) {
    if *genErr != nil {
        return
    }
    npmLib.ProjectName = GetProjectName(genErr)
}
```

I want to pass `projectName` variable from `run.go`to `shell.sh`.  How to do this using golang?

I used `$` in `shell.sh`. It didn't work.

Comment: Please format the question properly. It's unreadable.

Comment: @mkopriva I am unable to do. I am new here.

Answer (score 1):

**a.sh**

```sh
echo $PassedName
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // run your shell script
    // don't forget to mention ./
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "./a.sh")

    // whatever variable you want to pass append it to cmd.Env
    // it's format is of key=value
    cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "PassedName=hello")
    // set stdout and stderr appropriately as per your needs
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Run() // run the cmd
}
```